# cppcheck does not expand macro when checking C code?

Tags: macros, expand, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I have code like below, and I use cppcheck to do static analysis.
I found that it cannot report null pointer for data.

```
#define MY_FREE(p) if(p) {free(p);(p)=NULL;}

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    ret = list_insert(list, data);
    if (1 != ret)
    {
        MY_FREE(data);
    }

    other_process(data->item);
}
```

But if I expand macro "MY_FREE" directly, it worked.

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    ret = list_insert(list, data);
    if (1 != ret)
    {
        if(data) {free(data);(data)=NULL;};
    }

    other_process(data->item);
}
```

Is there any configuration can resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer. What is the exact code your testing? Cppcheck warns about this code:

```
#define MY_FREE(p) if(p) {free(p);(p)=NULL;}

void f() {
    struct Data *data;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        ret = list_insert(list, data);
        if (1 != ret)
        {
             MY_FREE(data);
        }
        other_process(data->item);
    }
}
```

Reported warning:

[1.c:12]: (warning) Possible null pointer dereference: data

In your code.. it sounds like that we have false negatives for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please replace "other_process(data->item);" with "other_process0(data); other_process1(data->item);", and try again?

Comment: It is not known what `other_process0(data);` does, it might reassign `data` so it is not NULL anymore. Therefore Cppcheck does not warn about that.

Comment: Even if `data` might reassign in `other_process0` , it's impossible to change `data` in `f()`, right?

Comment: Almost. `other_process0` could be a macro. The macro `MY_FREE` assigns `data`. It is such a common pattern, we have to assume it might be a macro. If you add a function/macro declaration for `other_process0` you should see the warning. Anyway.. I am certain that there are bugs that Cppcheck should detect but fails to detect and it is very unfortunate. If you see such bugs then I would like to know about it. This require "data flow analysis" and there will never be a tool that does this perfectly.